# Log all outgoing mail from PHP on a Redhat box

Tags: php, redhat, email, blacklist-prevention

The IP of one of our servers has been blacklisted and I would like to attempt to work out why. There are many Apache virtualhosts on the server so the logging would need to be split up by domain and if possible include the PHP script file name that initiated the mail call.

The mail server is Qmail and the server is running Redhat Linux.

Is this possible? If so please detail how to achieve this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up going the sendmail wrapper route using the following resource: http://kb.parallels.com/1711

> There is a way to find what the folder
>   the PHP script that sends mail was run
>   from. Note, the paths can be slightly
>   differ from the listed below depending
>   on your OS and Plesk version:
>
> 1) create
>   /var/qmail/bin/sendmail-wrapper script
>   with the content:
>
> !/bin/sh (echo X-Additional-Header: $PWD ;cat) | tee -a
>   /var/tmp/mail.send|/var/qmail/bin/sendmail-qmail
>   "$@"
>
> Note, it should be the two lines
>   including '#!/bin/sh'. 2) then create
>   log file /var/tmp/mail.send and grant
>   it "a+rw" rights, make the wrapper
>   e> xecutable, rename old sendmail and
>   link it to the new wrapper: ~# touch
>   /var/tmp/mail.send ~# chmod a+rw
>   /var/tmp/mail.send ~# chmod a+x
>   /var/qmail/bin/sendmail-wrapper ~# mv
>   /var/qmail/bin/sendmail
>   /var/qmail/bin/sendmail-qmail ~# ln -s
>   /var/qmail/bin/sendmail-wrapper
>   /var/qmail/bin/sendmail 3) Wait for an
>   hour or so and revert sendmail back:
>
> ~# rm -f /var/qmail/bin/sendmail ~# ln
>   -s /var/qmail/bin/sendmail-qmail /var/qmail/bin/sendmail
>
> Examine /var/tmp/mail.send file, there
>   should be lines starting with
>   "X-Additional-Header:" pointing out to
>   domains' folders where the scripts
>   which sent the mail are located.  You
>   can see all the folders mail PHP
>   scripts were run from with the
>   following command:
>
> ~# grep X-Additional
>   /var/tmp/mail.send | grep `cat
>   /etc/psa/psa.conf | grep
>   HTTPD_VHOSTS_D | sed -e
>   's/HTTPD_VHOSTS_D//'`
>
> f you see no output from the command
>   above, it means that no mail was sent
>   using PHP mail() function from the
>   Plesk virtual hosts directory.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about logging the PHP script or any of the webserver-related bits, but qmail (and pretty much every other MTA) typically logs what was sent -- at least the MAIL FROM & RCPT TO addresses & the mail server it handed the message off to.

You can probably parse your qmail logs to have an idea of what was/is being sent that could have gotten you blacklisted.
Additionally if you know which blacklist(s) you're on that may give you a clue as to what was going on.

Comment: I thought of the qmail logs, but it doesn't appear to be logging. I really need to be able to split the logs by source as well. So that could be VHost name or `pwd` (the directory it was executed in).

Comment: If your mail server isn't logging (at a minimum) the `MAIL FROM` / `RCPT TO` addresses & the server it's handing the message off to you should probably fix that - it's the path of least resistance for troubleshooting anything mail-related :-).  Re: splitting the log, you can do that based on the `MAIL FROM` address (which may not be 100% accurate, but it's a good start) - doing more may require some custom hackery in either PHP, qmail or both...

Answer (score 0):

If you're running PHP 5.3 or later you can have PHP log all the info you're looking for automatically, no wrapper scripts required:

http://php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php